# Using multiprocessing module in class

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have the following program and I want to use multiprocessing module. It uses external files, in which I call the PSO class from another file. `costfunc` is a function from another file and the other args are just variables.

`Swarm` is a list containing as much objects as the value of `ps`, and each object has multiple attributes which need to update at every iteration.

Following Hannu implemented multiprocessing.pool and it is working, however it is taking much more time than running sequentially.

Would appreciate if you could tell me what are the reasons for it happening and how can I make it run faster?

```
# IMPORT PACKAGES -----------------------------------------------------------+
    import random
    import numpy as np
    # IMPORT FILES --------------------------------------------------------------+
    from Reducer import initial

    # Particle Class ------------------------------------------------------------+
    class Particle:
        def __init__(self,D,bounds_x,bounds_v):
            self.Position_i = []          # particle position
            self.Velocity_i = []          # particle velocity
            self.Cost_i = -1              # cost individual
            self.Position_Best_i = []     # best position individual
            self.Cost_Best_i = -1         # best cost individual
            self.Constraint_Best_i = []   # best cost individual contraints 
            self.Constraint_i = []        # constraints individual
            self.Penalty_i = -1           # constraints individual  

            x0,v0 = initial(D,bounds_x,bounds_v)

            for i in range(0,D):
                self.Velocity_i.append(v0[i])
                self.Position_i.append(x0[i])

        # evaluate current fitness
        def evaluate(self,costFunc,i):
            self.Cost_i, self.Constraint_i,self.Penalty_i = costFunc(self.Position_i,i)

            # check to see if the current position is an individual best
            if self.Cost_i < self.Cost_Best_i or self.Cost_Best_i == -1:
                self.Position_Best_i = self.Position_i
                self.Cost_Best_i = self.Cost_i
                self.Constraint_Best_i = self.Constraint_i
                self.Penalty_Best_i = self.Penalty_i

            return self

    def proxy(gg, costf, i):
        print(gg.evaluate(costf, i))


    # Swarm Class ---------------------------------------------------------------+
    class PSO():
        def __init__(self,costFunc,bounds_x,bounds_v,ps,D,maxiter):

            self.Cost_Best_g = -1       # Best Cost for Group
            self.Position_Best_g = []   # Best Position for Group
            self.Constraint_Best_g = []
            self.Penalty_Best_g = -1

            # Establish Swarm
            Swarm = []
            for i in range(0,ps):
                Swarm.append(Particle(D,bounds_x,bounds_v))

            # Begin optimization Loop
            i = 1
            self.Evol = []
            while i <= maxiter:
                pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = 4)
                results = pool.map_async(partial(proxy, costf = costFunc, i=i), Swarm)
                pool.close()
                pool.join()

                Swarm = results.get()

                if Swarm[j].Cost_i< self.Cost_Best_g or self.Cost_Best_g == -1:
                        self.Position_Best_g = list(Swarm[j].Position_i)
                        self.Cost_Best_g = float(Swarm[j].Cost_i)
                        self.Constraint_Best_g = list(Swarm[j].Constraint_i)
                        self.Penalty_Best_g = float(Swarm[j].Penalty_i)

                self.Evol.append(self.Cost_Best_g)
                i += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a proxy function to do the function call, and as you need to deliver arguments to the function, you will need `partial` as well. Consider this:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        self.b = None

    def evaluate(self, CostFunction, i):
        xyzzy = CostFunction(i)
        sleep(0.01)
        self.b = self.a*xyzzy
        return self

def CostFunc(i):
    return i*i

def proxy(gg, costf, i):
    return gg.evaluate(costf, i)

def main():
    Swarm = []
    for i in range(0,10):
        nc = Foo(i)
        Swarm.append(nc)

    p = Pool()
    for i in range(100,102):
        results = p.map_async(partial(proxy, costf=CostFunc, i=i), Swarm)
    p.close()
    p.join()

    Swarm = []
    for a in results.get():
        Swarm.append(a)

    for s in Swarm:
        print (s.b)

main()
```

This creates a `Swarm` list of objects, and within each of these objects is `evaluate` that is the function you need to call. Then we have parameters (CostFunc and an integer as in your code).

We will now use `Pool.map_async` to map your Swarm list to your pool. This gives each worker one instance of `Foo` from your Swarm list, and we have a `proxy` function that actually calls then `evaluate()`.

However, as `apply_async` only sends an object from the iterable to the function, instead of using `proxy` as the target function to pool, we use `partial` to create the target function to pass the "fixed" arguments.

And as you apparently want to get the modified objects back, this requires another trick. If you modify the target object in Pool process, it just modifies the local copy and throws it away as soon as the processing completes. There would be no way for the subprocess to modify main process memory anyway (or vice versa), this would cause a segmentation fault.

Instead, after modifying the object, we return `self`. When your pool has completed its work, we discard the old `Swarm` and reassemble it from the result objects.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Think I understood, however in your example the CostFunc is not inside evaluate, so not doing anything. How can I change to include it?

Comment: It can of course be anywhere. I edited my answer and moved the call to CostFunction into the evaluate method.   The same principle applies. Proxy calls evaluate, and the rest is just setting the function parameters right.

Comment: It is working, but after the pool the objects' attributes which should have something now are empty.

Comment: Ok. that is a completely different problem then. Basically not solvable by multiprocessing, as your subprocesses only modify the local copy of the object passed to the subprocess. There is no way you can modify the object in the main process memory from a subprocess as this would cause a segmentation fault. Let me think if there is an easy workaround.

Comment: Edited the code above so it might help you. Appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: This is the best I can do. I modified my answer once again. You cannot modify the objects directly, but you can return `self` from your worker and reassemble your `swarm` based on this.  If this does not work, then I am afraid you might be out of options.

Comment: It worked! I said the new Swarm was equal to results.get(). Thanks so much, owe you one.

Comment: Since my costFunc is basically elementary mathematical operations is it expected that with multiprocessing it actually takes longer than sequential despite having large amount of data to process ?

Comment: That one is a bit tricky. CPU heavy processing generally benefits from multiprocessing, but the drawback is that if data structures are large (in this case your objects in Swarm class), serialising this and transferring via a queue to and from the subprocess can take more time than you gain by parallelism (this is what happens under the hood).  This is always a bit of a trial and error.